# Is there any way to give control back to app from Cordova InAppBrowser after it redirected to another page from the URL which was opened initially

Tags: cordova, redirect, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

Hi I am trying to integrate with a payment gateway .I am using cordova InAppbrowser plugin to open bank pages from ionic app.After a successful/failed payment , It is redirected back to a redirection url configured at the bank side.
I want to get back to ionic mobile app page from redirected html page.  How can I do this other than when the user clicks back button.

Also "Done" button in iOS is not getting displayed in the second page ( ie redirected html page,hosted by me) but is getting displayed on the bank page.

Can anyone please help me here.

Comment: This link has the required answer.
https://dbwriteups.wordpress.com/2016/01/23/adding-a-done-button-to-androids-inappbrowser/